# Increase/decrease playback speed in rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, playback

How do I increase or decrease the playback speed in rhythmbox 3.0.1 the way its possible on VLC using <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys? I am fine if I need to install a plugin for this.

There is a similar question on LP, albeit it doesn't have answers:

- [Does rythmbox have the ability to change playback speed?](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+question/56290)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### RBPitch

What you describe fits nicely into the capabilities of an external plugin called RBPitch.

From the [launchpad description](https://launchpad.net/rbpitch):

> rbpitch is a plugin for Rhythmbox that lets you change the pitch,
> tempo, and speed in real-time while playing a song. The main features
> of rbpitch include:
>
> *Change the pitch and tempo of your music independently of each other.
>
> *Change the "speed", which is pitch+tempo scaled together without aliasing.

**to install - for RB2.96 & RB 2.97**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:smcnam/rbpitch-release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rbpitch
```

In Rhythmbox, go to the Plugins manager via the Edit -> Plugins menu. Make sure the checkbox next to "Pitch and Tempo Shifting" is checked.

**RB2.98 and beyond**

There hasn't been any code changes since the RB2.97 release - thus this plugin is only applicable for Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10.

Considerable changes to the Rhythmbox menu structure etc has been made since RB 2.99 - so whilst it may be possible to switch your sources back to 12.10 to get it to run on RB2.98/RB2.99 and RB3.0, I'm doubtful.  Its probably better to throw an issue onto the [OP's issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/rbpitch) to see future plans.

Comment: It seems like I am stuck with an unrolvable dependency if I change the source to 12.10, that of installing librhythmbox-core6, which is obsolete. Some other workaround possible?

Comment: It is a C++ plugin - thus will need compiling.  You may have some luck with creating a symbolic link to librhythmbox-core6.so.0 (or whatever the library is called) - as I said, I'm doubtful - its better to contact the OP.  I know he is still active since he pops up on the rhythmbox mailing list occasionally.

Comment: Filed a bug as you said: https://bugs.launchpad.net/rbpitch/+bug/1300752

Comment: [The rbpitch page at launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/rbpitch) now says that "*Ubuntu 16.04 is the latest supported release of Ubuntu that will work with rbpitch, and many versions later than 12.04 but earlier than 16.04 will not work.*"